# How to implement function in interface with generic argument types?

Tags: java, oop, generics

```
public interface Page<T> {
  T nextPage();
}
```

And it's implementation

```
public class ConcretePageA implements Page<TypeA> {
  public TypeA nextPage() {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Then I have an interface that consumes `Page`

```
public interface Source {
  <T> int getData(Page<T> page)
}
```

And its implementation

```
public class ConcreteSourceA implements Source {
  public int getData(Page<TypeA> page) {   //error: getData in ConcreteSourceA clashes with getData in Source
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I tried this but it won't work either

```
public class ConcreteSourceA implements Source {
  public <TypeA> getData(Page<TypeA> page) { // error: expect com.foo.TypeA but got TypeA
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

When I do the above I get a compile error saying

```
getData in ConcreteSourceA clashes with getData in Source
```

I know I am doing something wrong, but how do i fix it while still having multiple implementations that uses different types?

Am I just doing this wrong in the first place? Is Generics not the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to make `Source` generic much like `Page` is - like so:

```java
public interface Source<T> {
  int getData(Page<T> page);
}
```

You can then define implementations that only implement certain specializations of that like

```java
public class ConcreteSourceA implements Source<TypeA> {
  public int getData(Page<TypeA> page) {
    // do stuff
    return 0;
  }
}
```